# How to get dynamically changing width of div jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="video_wrpr" style="width: 1920px; left: -301px;">
            <div class="video1" style="width: 296.008px;">
```

This is my html code. I want to calculate width of video1 which changes dynamically and multiply with some number in my case 8 and changes the width of video_wrpr.

```
element.style {
width: 296.008px;
}
.video1 {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 235px;
margin-left: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
height: 174px;
}
```

This is the style of that div, then width in element style is dynamically changing width while resizing screen. while am trying to get width of that div using width(). It gaves me result as 235px not 296px.

Then i used $window.resize to get dynamic width of that div

```
jQuery(function($){

     $(window).resize(function(e) {
            $('.video1').each(function() {
                slwidth = $(this).width();
             });
     });
    var sliderLength=parseInt(jQuery('.video_wrpr .video1').length);
    $('.video_wrpr').width((sliderLength*slwidth));
```

If i used this I want to use **slwidth** variable as global variable, I don't how to achieve.

I want to know this is the only way or any other way exist??

Answer (score 0):

just declare `slwidth` outside all of your functions:

```
var slwidth = 0;
jQuery(function($){

 $(window).resize(function(e) {
        $('.video1').each(function() {
            slwidth = $(this).width();
         });
 });
var sliderLength=parseInt(jQuery('.video_wrpr .video1').length);
$('.video_wrpr').width((sliderLength*slwidth));
```